# Big integer to octal in javascript

Tags: javascript

Looking for a way to convert a big integer into octal notation in javascript.

The standard 12457472939742322323232.toString(8) will truncate and return something like 16452431526650000000000000. Anyone know of a good built-in way to do this, or do I need to hack something together?

(note: these are completely made up numbers)

EDIT:
Ok, so I have a huge hex string that represents an octal number, I was trying to use `parseInt(hexStr, 16).toString(8)` however clearly the number is too big to fit in a standard JS number. So how can I take this hex string to a base 8 BigNumber?

Comment: Numbers this big are not supported by JS directly. You will have computation problems. Try following code: `var a = 12457472939742322323232; var b = a; b--; console.log(a === b)`

Comment: Where is the integer coming from? What is the octal used for? You can't have that large number because it's too big for the Number type. You need to make it a string or a custom object.

Comment: @JJJ please see my edit! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's starting out as hex, you can convert it to binary character by character then to oct:

```js
function hex2oct( hex ) {

 const pad0s = ( str, bits ) => str.padStart( Math.ceil( str.length / bits ) * bits, "0" );

 const binary = pad0s( hex.split( "" ).map( char => pad0s( parseInt( char, 16 ).toString( 2 ), 4 ) ).join( "" ), 3 );

 let octal = "";

 for ( let i = 0; i < binary.length; i += 3 )
  octal += parseInt( binary.slice( i, i + 3 ), 2 ).toString( 8 );

 return octal;

}

console.log( hex2oct( "2A3522A842CDE4D6F20" ) );
```

Conversion between any 2-power bases can be done quite trivially. Other bases it's easier to just use a big number library.